# Why do some methods use dot notation and others don't?

Tags: python, methods, syntax

So, I'm just beginning to learn Python (using Codecademy), and I'm a bit confused.

Why are there some methods that take an argument, and others use the dot notation?

len() takes an arugment, but won't work with the dot notation:

```
>>> len("Help")
4
>>>"help".len()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'len'
```

And likewise:

```
>>>"help".upper()
'HELP'
>>>upper("help")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'upper' is not defined
```

Comment: Guido explains here: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-does-python-use-methods-for-some-functionality-e-g-list-index-but-functions-for-other-e-g-len-list.htm

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The key word here is method. There is a slight difference between a function and a method.

#### Method

Is a function that is defined in the class of the given object. For example:

```
class Dog:
    def bark(self):
        print 'Woof woof!'

rufus = Dog()
rufus.bark() # called from the object
```

#### Function

A function is a globally defined procedure:

```
def bark():
    print 'Woof woof!'
```

As for your question regarding the `len` function, the globally defined function calls the object's `__len__` special method. So in this scenario, it is an issue of readability.

Otherwise, methods are better when they apply only to certain objects. Functions are better when they apply to multiple objects. For example, how can you uppercase a number? You wouldn't define that as a function, you'd define it as only a method only in the string class.

Comment: So, just to confirm - in my example above, len() is a global function, where as upper() is a method of the string class?

Comment: You don't really go over class specific function vs function that takes arguments.

Comment: Fishy, that is correct. Methods are better when they apply only to certain objects. Functions are better when they apply to multiple objects. For example, how can you uppercase a number. You would define that as a function, you'd define it as only a string method.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi You can `lower()` a crane and you can `lower()` a string yet it's a method. The truth is, Python developers made a mistake when they defined `len()` and the other similar functions; if we end up defining `__len__()` anyways, why not just have `len` method in the first place?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Not all objects implement `__len__` either, you *can not* `len()` an integer for example. There's no difference between the use cases and implementations of `len` and `lower`, other than `len` straight up calling `__len__`.

Answer (score 3):

What you call "dot notation" are class methods and they only work for classes that have the method defined by the class implementer. `len` is a builtin function that takes one argument and returns the size of that object. A class may implement a method called `len` if its wants to, but most don't. The builtin `len` function has a rule that says if a class has a method called `__len__`, it will use it, so this works:

```
>>> class C(object):
...     def __len__(self):
...             return 100
... 
>>> len(C())
100
```

`"help".upper` is the opposite. The string class defines a method called `upper`, but that doesn't mean there has to be a function called `upper` also. It turns out that there is an `upper` function in the `string` module, but generally you don't have to implement an extra function just because you implemented a class method.

Comment: What's with the 4 underscores and the 'self' part? (I'm really new to this) @tdelany

Comment: @danielcg, in Python's classes, `self` represents the current instance of the class (in this case an instance of `C`). Methods surrounded by underscores (like `__len__`) are usually called internally by Python at some point, but they're just a name -- nothing special (in this case, `C.__len__` is called by `len`, as another example, `__init__` is a class initializer).

Answer (score 3):

This is the difference between a *function* and a *method.* If you are only just learning the basics, maybe simply accept that this difference exists, and that you will eventually understand it.

Still here? It's not even hard, actually. In object-oriented programming, methods are preferred over functions for many things, because that means one type of object can override *its* version of the method without affecting the rest of the system.

For example, let's pretend you had a new kind of string where accented characters should lose their accent when you call `.upper()`. Instances of this type can subclass `str` and behave exactly the same in every other aspect, basically for free; all they need to redefine is the `upper` method (and even then, probably call the method of the base class and only change the logic when you handle an accented lowercase character). And software which expects to work on strings will just continue to work and not even know the difference if you pass in an object of this new type where a standard `str` is expected.

A design principle in Python is that *everything is an object.* This means you can create your own replacements even for basic fundamental objects like `object`, `class`, and `type`, i.e. extend or override the basic language for your application or platform.

In fact, this happened in Python 2 when `unicode` strings were introduced to the language. A lot of application software continued to work exactly as before, but now with `unicode` instances where previously the code had been written to handle `str` instances. (This difference no longer exists in Python 3; or rather, the type which was called `str` and was used almost everywhere is now called `bytes` and is only used when you specifically want to handle data which is not text.)

Going back to our new `upper` method, think about the opposite case; if `upper` was just a function in the standard library, how would you even think about modifying software which needs `upper` to behave differently? What if tomorrow your boss wants you to do the same for `lower`? It would be a huge undertaking, and the changes you would have to make all over the code base would easily tend towards a spaghetti structure, as well as probably introduce subtle new bugs.

This is one of the cornerstones of object-oriented programming, but it probably only *really* makes ense when you learn the other two or three principles in a more structured introduction. For now, perhaps the quick and dirty summary is "methods make the implementation modular and extensible."

Comment: You might ask why `len` is *not* a method and that would be a very good question. I *think* the brief explanation is "legacy".